# How to move html elements using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, menu

Is it possible to attach html tag to others using Javascript?

`<li>` to other `<li>` ?

For instance, I'm creating dropdown menu.
I have div separate from the `<ul>` tag

```
<ul>
  <li>menu1</li>
  <li>menu2</li>
</ul>

<div id="submenu1">
     <li>sub1</li>
     <li>sub2</li>
</div>
```

When I click, say, a link, then I want sub menu to show up under menu1 so result would be like:

```
<ul>
  <li>menu1</li>
  <div id="submenu1">
     <li>sub1</li>
     <li>sub2</li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

The reason why I choose `<div>` to be separated from beginning instead of nested in `<li>` tag is that if I set the `<div>` "hide", it hides but it occupies the space and created big space between menu1 and any content below, so my page looks weird like:

```
mypage
----------------------------
| menu1
|
|                  <------ big open space div is hiding
|             
|
| hello content start here
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for the tip guys, I've solved the problem with removing div and have nested `<ul>` per suggestion. The elements are still being shifted when submenu shows up but used CSS position:absolute and specifying z-index helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `display: none` in your CSS then the hidden element doesn't need any space:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>menu1
    <ul id="submenu1">
       <li>sub1</li>
       <li>sub2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="active">menu2
    <ul id="submenu1">
      <li>sub1</li>
      <li>sub2</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li ul {
  display: none;
}

li.active {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is invalid HTML. A li should be contained in either a `ol` or a `ul` element. Change

```
<div id="submenu1">
     <li>sub1</li>
     <li>sub2</li>
</div>
```

to

```
<ul id="submenu1">
     <li>sub1</li>
     <li>sub2</li>
</ul>
```

For your main problem, there is no need to put the div (or ideally ul) outside the main ul. When you hide an element by setting its `visibility` to `hidden`, it will still take up the empty space. To complete hide it and remove any space it was taking, set the `display` CSS property to `none`.

```
document.getElementById('submenu1').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually you put the submenu in another `<ul>` inside an `<li>` in your main menu (so that you get valid HTML), and hide it with `display: none` CSS property and show it on click.

```
  <ul>
    <li><a href="menu1">menu item 1</a><ul class="submenu">
      <li>sub 1</li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a hrf="menu2">menu item 2</a></li>
  </u>
```

Then in your CSS (or added using js):

```
  ul.submenu {
     display: none;
  }
  a:hover + ul.submenu, ul.submenu:hover {
     display: block;
  }
```

This one will work on modern browsers without any js! But you can do it with js too, of course.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually done via CSS. You have the entire menu pre-created (note that nesting `<div>` within `<ul>` is invalid HTML):

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>menu1
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>sub1</li>
      <li>sub2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and then you declare in CSS:

```
ul.submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

Now you can remove or add the "submenu" CSS class from the `<ul>` through JavaScript, or you set the `.style.display` property.

Or even more elegantly (but less cross-browser compatible, if you still care for old browsers), entirely without JavaScript through pure CSS:

```
ul.menu > li:hover ul.submenu {
  display: block;
}
ul.submenu:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
  <li>menu1</li>
  <div id="submenu1" style="display: none">
     <li>sub1</li>
     <li>sub2</li>
  </div>
  <li>menu2</li>
</ul>
```

Try it, this will make the div take up no space. if you use visiblity: hidden then it will take up space.